# ASP.NET MVC5 Custom Attribute on Parameter is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-attributes

I have a custom attribute I am using:

```
public class Plus.ViewModels {

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Constructor, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class ExcludeFilterAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string FilterToExclude { get; private set; }
        public ExcludeFilterAttribute(string filterToExclude)
        {
            this.FilterToExclude = filterToExclude;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using it on the parameter to a Controller's action like so:

```
public class MyController 
{
     public ActionResult AggregationClientBase([ExcludeFilter("Categories")] AggregationFiltersViewModel filters)
     {
         return View(filters);
     }
}
```

I then want to read the value of the custom attribute in the View like this:
Type type = Model.GetType();

```
@model AggregationFiltersViewModel
@{
    Type type = Model.GetType();
    ExcludeFilterAttribute[] AttributeArray = (ExcludeFilterAttribute[])type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExcludeFilterAttribute), false);

    ExcludeFilterAttribute fa = AttributeArray[0];   
}
```

Then

```
@if (fa.FilterToExclude != "Categories")           
{
    <th>Category:</th>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategoryId, Model.Categories)</td>
}
```

However, the array of custom attributes is empty, so I get the following error:

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

How can I get the value of the custom attribute?
I know I can just pass values model variables, but using a custom attribute makes is easier when I have a large collection to exclude.

Comment: The attribute is defined inside method `AggregationClientBase` of controller class, not view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get attribute from model, but it is defined inside method `AggregationClientBase` in your controller.

So:

```
var controllerType = typeof(YourController);
var method = controllerType.GetMethod("AggregationClientBase");
var parameter = method.GetParameters().First(p => p.Name == "filters");

var fa = parameter.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExcludeFilterAttribute), false)
                  .First() as ExcludeFilterAttribute;
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean it is defining in on the first parameter to the method?

`public ActionResult AggregationClientBase([ExcludeFilter("Categories")] AggregationFiltersViewModel filters)`

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get your sentence. You mean that I've put name? Or what?

Comment: Sorry, I thought putting 


`[ExcludeFilter("Categories")] AggregationFiltersViewModel filters`


defines the attribute on the filters view model?

Comment: No. If you want to put in view model you need to write: `[ExcludeFilter("Categories")] public class AggregationFiltersViewModel  { ... }`. Then you code will work.

Comment: Okay, great thanks for your help. Is either way considered best practice or have performance issues?

Comment: @RhysStephens Definitely - in my opinion you should cache `fa` instance - once get, save it into memory cache. You can build composite key for memory cache from controller name and action name (example only).

Comment: FYI, I am going to be reusing the AggregationFiltersViewModel many times, but sometimes I will exclude different fields from displaying in the view. I could be doing a bad thing, but I thought it would be a good way.

Comment: @RhysStephensI think it is good way - just cache `fa` instances (they can be different for each action) and it should work.